# how to avoid refreshing a div. if the div has been used?

Tags: jquery, vb.net

i have a div inside a iframe. It will be refreshing very 10 seconds.
the div place holder has 4 text boxes controls. if any of the textbox is used then i want to not to refresh the div.

Comment: How is the div refreshing? Is it the entire web page inside the iFrame which is refreshing?

Comment: right.. not enough info.  where is the script controlling the refresh.. inside the iframe or out?

Answer (score 0):

You can mark mark the div whenever any of the textbox has been used. You can add a new class to the div with the .addClass('used'), and then when refreshing filtering out the divs that do not contain that class:

```
$(".myDivClass:not(.used)")
```